# VimのプラグインまたはLinuxのツールで関数の使い方を教えてくれるツールはありませんか？

Tags: python, c++, linux, c, vim

使用する言語はPythonとC/C++で、PyCharmやCLionの様に関数の使い方を教えてくれる機能を提供してくれるツールをそれぞれの言語環境で探しています｡

これらのIDEを導入すれば済む話ではあるのですが、Vimのプラグインやコマンドに慣れてしまっているため現在の操作環境を崩さずに導入できるようなツールを探しています。

ご存知の方はいらっしゃいませんでしょうか？よろしくお願いします｡

Answer (score 1):

`vim`の設定が`~/.vim`配下にあるという前提で回答します。

`~/.vim/ftplugin`に`c.vim`と`python.vim`を作成し、以下のように追記すると<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>で参照できそうです。
確かデフォルトで[c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)でも`c.vim`を読んでくれると思いますがうまくいかないようなら`cpp.vim`を作成して`c.vim`と同じ内容を追記してください。

```sh
$ cat c.vim
```

> ```
> let $MANPAGER = "vim -M +MANPAGER -" 
> if has('terminal')
>     let &l:keywordprg = ':terminal ++close ++norestore man 3'
>     " or
>     "let &l:keywordprg = ":vertical terminal ++close ++norestore man 3"
> else
>     let &l:keywordprg = 'man 3'
> endif
> ```

```sh
$ cat python.vim
```

> ```
> " Uncomment for your needs.
> "let $LESS = substitute($LESS,'--quit-if-one-screen\>','','g')
> if has('terminal')
>     let &l:keywordprg = ':terminal ++close ++norestore pydoc3
>     " or
>     "let &l:keywordprg = ":vertical terminal ++close ++norestore pydoc3"
> else
>     let &l:keywordprg = 'pydoc3'
> endif
> ```

より詳しいことは`vim`で`:help keywordprg`してみてください。

`man`を日本語化したい場合はDebian/Ubuntu系なら`manpages-ja`と`manpages-ja-dev`をインストールすることができます。

```sh
sudo apt install manpages-ja manpages-ja-dev
```

`pydoc3`を日本語化することは残念ながらできません。詳しくは[pydoc/pydoc3を日本語化することはできますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/53728/25936)を参照してください。

Comment: とても便利なシステムをありがとうございます
しかしC言語だと他の関数の情報まで出てきてしまうのとintやmainの様なものの説明をしているものはないのでしょうか

Comment: @Hiroyuki Yoshinaga 返信が遅くなってしまい申し訳ありません Hiroyuki Yoshinagaさんの設定はどこで書けば良いのでしょうか？ python.vimもvimrcもエラーになってしまうのですが

Comment: @queu1829 さん、Hiroyuki Yoshinaga さんのコメントを元に 伽語蓮弥 さんが質問を改善してくださいました。それに伴い一連のコメントを削除するなど整理しています。新しい質問文で問題が解決していないかお試しいただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

どうしても日本語にしたければ、まずその日本語ドキュメントが必要になり、次にそれを閲覧するツールとの連携が必要になります
手っ取り早いのは[Python 3.7.3 ドキュメント](https://docs.python.org/ja/)などのWebのデータを使ってやることでしょう
例えば、ターミナルで使える Web ブラウザ w3m を使うなら、以前の queu1829 さんが書き込まれた関数をちょっと変えてやって、次のようにします

```
function! s:pyhelp(word) abort
    execute 'terminal ++close w3m -o confirm_qq=0 https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functions.html\\#' . a:word
endfunction
command! -nargs=1 PyHelp call <SID>pyhelp(<f-args>)
setlocal keywordprg=:PyHelp
```

execute の部分はもちろん他のブラウザでも良いですし、これまで CLI の ブラウザを使ったことがなければ、firefox でも構いません