# pydoc/pydoc3を日本語化することはできますか？

Tags: python, python3, ubuntu

[vimのプラグインまたはlinuxのツールで関数の使い方を教えてくれるツールはありませんか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/53679/25936)という質問に[回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/53682/25936)しました。
その回答に対して質問者さんからできるのなら`pydoc`/`pydoc3`を日本語で読みたいと希望されたのですが、`vim`の`keywordprg`を利用して何らかの方法で日本語化したものを参照できるようにすることは可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pydoc`はソースコードに埋め込まれたコメントを元に表示する仕組みなので、日本語で読みたい場合には元のPythonコードにあらかじめ日本語でコメントが記述されている必要があります。

[Pydoc - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pydoc)

> Pydoc is used to extract documentation from the source code itself.
>   (訳文)
>   Pydocはソースコード自体からドキュメントを抽出するために使用されます。

[perl](/questions/tagged/perl) の`perldoc`や [java](/questions/tagged/java) の`javadoc`、[Doxygen](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxygen) なども同じように埋め込みのコメントからドキュメントを生成・表示する仕組みです。

---

参考までに、(参照している元質問にある) `man`コマンドに関しては、manページという独立したフォーマット(ファイル)に分かれており、多言語対応もしているので、翻訳さえされていれば設定した言語での表示が可能です。